# How do i fix my current chart is not exporting its filename in my userform? everytime i have to rename the chart in order to work

Tags: image, charts

My image is set by current chart pics that can be replace from one chart to another. The code works fine until i close my saved excel file. The problem arises when i open my file and try to use the code and it indicates Loading picture error, my `Image1.picture` is nothing.

The code is working fine, since i started deleting some chart and rename the other chart with its number. the file would run correctly until i have exit the file. Now, whenever i open my file it could not locate or load the image file until i have to retype the chart number again even though the name box of the chart is correct. Then the code works again

```
Private Sub `Cmdnext`_Click()    
If `chartnum` = 2 Then   
    `chartnum` = 1   
Else
    `chartnum` = `chartnum` + 1   
    End If   
    GetChart
    End Sub

    GetChart


    Private Sub GetChart()    
    Set CurrentChart = Sheets("Graph").ChartObjects(chartnum).Chart

    picFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "mychart.gif"   
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=picFileName, Filtername:="GIF"

    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(picFileName)   

    Select Case chartnum     
        Case Is = 1    
            Frame1.Visible = False    
            Frame2.Visible = False            
        Case Is = 2
            Frame1.Visible = True       
            Frame2.Visible = False    

    End Select

End Sub
```

I expect no more error 481 invalid picture when opening the file

Comment: How about you add some tags about the technology you're using, so people don't have to open your question to see if they want to answer it.